# Obtener Fecha y hora para enviar a una variable tipo struct en c++

Tags: c++

Saludos cordiales, tengo una consulta agradezco su gentil apoyo:

```
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

//Fecha basado en el sistema actual de Sistema operativo
time_t now= time(0); // captura fecga y hora actual

tm *time =localtime(&now); //ceamo el puntero time y se referencia objeto time y se guarda en var now
cout << "Dia de la semana:" << time->tm_wday << endl;  //accedemos al objeto time y miemto

system("Pause");
return 0;
}
```

la pregunta es como envío la fecha y hora a una variable en c++

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Esta es la definicion de la estructura tm:

```
struct tm {
    int tm_sec;         /* seconds */
    int tm_min;         /* minutes */
    int tm_hour;        /* hours */
    int tm_mday;        /* day of the month */
    int tm_mon;         /* month */
    int tm_year;        /* year */
    int tm_wday;        /* day of the week */
    int tm_yday;        /* day in the year */
    int tm_isdst;       /* daylight saving time */
};
```

Puedes leer los datos y almacenarlos en una variable o una estructura, pero si lo que quieres es un número único entonces solo usa now que es el numero de segundos transcurridos desde el primero de enero de 1970.

Comment: Excelente muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

> ¿Cómo envío la fecha y hora a una variable en C++?

Entiendo que por "enviar" la fecha y hora a una variable te refieres a guardar el dato. Si te refieres a eso ya lo has hecho:

```
tm *time =localtime(&now);
//  ~~~~ <-- fecha y hora guardadas en la variable time
```

Pero esta no es la manera C++ de hacerlo, la [estructura `tm`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/tm) pertenece a los tipos de datos de C. Para hacerlo en C++ debe usarse la cabecera [`<chrono>`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/chrono).

La cabecera `<chrono>` da acceso a diferentes relojes (reloj de sistema, reloj estable, reloj de alta resolución) y a varias utilidades para trabajar con medidas de tiempo. Para obtener la hora actual tan sólo escribe:

```
auto ahora = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
//   ~~~~~ <-- fecha y hora guardadas en la variable ahora
```

La llamada a `system_clock::now()` devuelve un objeto de tipo [`time_point`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/time_point) que puede ser usado con otras variables del mismo tipo para hacer operaciones (restar o sumar tiempo, comparar tiempos...).